# How to get value from bean ADF oracle in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oracle, input, javabeans, oracle-adf

I need to get a variable from bean ADF Oracle for using in function JavaScript to compare with the input value
variable from my bean:

```
private RichInputText username;
```

to compare with inputText

```
<af:inputText id="itUserName1" binding="#{loginBean.username}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the ADF Faces JavaScript API.
This will allow you to access the text item value from your javascript.
A guide is here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/1-2011-javascript-302460.pdf